# jQuery not working - 'jQuery was used before it was defined'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Note: I am new to Javascript and jQuery

I have this test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test Page</title>
<link href="_css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainArticle">
<h1>This is some test code</h1>
  <p>Lots of text to test this test co</p>
</div>

<script scr="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

This is in my CSS file:

```
.highlight {
background: #ffffcc;
}
```

Then in my JS file I have:

```
jQuery("#mainArticle").addClass("highlight");
```

I can't get this to work. The background of my div isn't getting 'highlight' applied. The error in my JS file keeps saying 'jQuery was used before it was defined'. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Please Check your jquery is loaded.

Comment: Is jquery in the same directory as your page? If it isn't, then put the path in the src="./path/to/jquery/jquery.js"

Comment: In chrome Inspector check in network tab if jQuery file is loaded. Also in console type `$` or `jQuery` to check if they are defined and working.

Comment: The jQuery file is in the same directory as my page.

Comment: There's error in your code `scr` should be `src` on line `<script scr="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes @abhishekkannojia write one. :)

Comment: @abhishekkannojia no one noticed :)

Comment: Does this solve your problem ? I'm moving it as an answer.

Comment: IT WAS THE ERROR! DING DING! Thank you so much. 'scr' should have been 'src'. God screw me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a syntax error in your code `scr` should be `src`

```
<script scr="jquery-1.11.3.min.js">
```

should be

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js">
```

Be careful of silly mistakes specially in HTML where you won't get any errors.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. I spent 12+ hours on this, lol. I suppose that's what happens when you are a newb to coding.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. It happens with all of us. ;P

Answer (score 1):

Instead of highlighting this div through JS file, you can call this script too:

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#mainArticle').addClass("highlight");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes this is the write way.You need to write addClass after dom ready.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried what you suggested... and it's still not working; the style isn't being applied.

Comment: You can use it like this too:
`$("#mainArticle").css("background-color","#ffffcc");`

Answer (score 1):

```
    //jQuery linked

    <script scr="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    //Perform Operation after jQuery Loaded
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#mainArticle').addClass("highlight");
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its working as suggested above, addClass works perfectly fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test Page</title>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#mainArticle').addClass("highlight");
   });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainArticle">
<h1>This is some test code</h1>
  <p>Lots of text to test this test co</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
// First try loading jQuery from Google's CDN
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

// Fall back to a local copy of jQuery if the CDN fails
<script>
window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="http://test.com/jquery.min.js"><\/script>'))
</script>
```

in your  js file

```
(function($) {

     $('#mainArticle').addClass("highlight");

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

By going through firebug Jquery is not defined such type of error caused by one of the following reason:-

JS file is not being properly loaded.
Your javascript run before the page is fully loaded.
You have edited the core Jquery file or a plugin may have overwritten the $ variable.

By going through the code it should be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test Page</title>
<link href="_css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.highlight {
background: #ffffcc;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="mainArticle">
<h1>This is some test code</h1>
  <p>Lots of text to test this test co</p>
</div>

<script scr="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#mainArticle").addClass("highlight");

</script>

</body>
</html>
```